# Despite waiting, still getting a StaleElementReferenceException with Selenium in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm creating a python script that automates creating user accounts for students, but its not working properly. The script pulls names, emails, and passwords from a excel file and fills them into the appropriate forms on the webpage and then waits for the user to enter the captcha and hit enter. It then waits to detect an element from the confirmation page before reloading and creating the next one.

My program works consistently for the first user, but after reloading the page and before filling in the forms it throws a StaleElement exception. I've searched around and seen that this is because it can't find the element that it is searching for on the page, so I've tried various types of wait to make sure the page is completely loaded. Even with these waits, it still throws the exception. There have been a few times and implementations where, after reloading, it will fill a few of the fields and then throw the exception. The main method of my code is as follows - if any other bits are needed I can provide them.

```
for i in xrange(sheet.nrows):
 driver.get("url")
 wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "id-of-element")))
 time.sleep(.5)
 read_from_config() #reads from a config file so the script knows which values to put where
 fill_common_forms() #method that fills forms that are the same for all users
 fill_specific_forms(i) #method that pulls from excel for user-specific data
 driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
 while True: #waits until the correct captcha has been entered
    handle_captcha(i)
    try:
        while True:
            if (driver.find_element_by_id("verify-your-email")):
                break
            time.sleep(1)
        break
    except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
        continue
 file.write("Account created for user "+sheet.row(i)[2].value+" with password "+sheet.row(i)[3].value+"\n")
```

I've even tried closing the driver and creating a new session with each loop, but that throws the exception as well. Any ideas ?

Comment: Is it possible to give link to the application

Comment: @Madhan, I actually figured out the issue but forgot to update my post here. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Alright, so I figured out what was wrong so I'm posting this just for posterity.

I thought I was getting the StaleElementReferenceException because the script was finding the elements initially but later failing to, which was partially true.

The read_from_config() file stored WebElement objects into dictionaries that I then looped through in order to preform operations on each element. The first time I looped through the dictionaries were empty, filled with WebElements from the page, and them looped through and the forms were filled etc. The page would then reload, and the elements from the refreshed page would be added to the dictionaries. However, the old elements were still in there, so the beginning of the loop would be trying to access WebElements from the old page that were no longer there.

Clearing the dictionaries at the end of each loop solved the issue.